# Pick the nth element of every group in a grouped dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

Suppose I create the following dataframe

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = rand(500), B = repeat(1:10, inner=50), C = 1:500)
```

and I can do a `groupby`:

```
grouped_df = groupby(df,"B")
```

I will end up with 10 groups. How can I choose, say, the third element of each group, and combine them into a new dataframe? That is, I would like a new dataframe of 10 rows, with each row being the third element of each of the groups?

I looked into `combine`, but couldn't find a solution. Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the third row from every group, `groupby` first and then `combine` using indexing:

```
julia> combine(groupby(df, :B), x->x[3, :])
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ B      A          C
     │ Int64  Float64    Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1  0.196572       3
   2 │     2  0.539942      53
   3 │     3  0.243455     103
   4 │     4  0.837491     153
   5 │     5  0.672861     203
   6 │     6  0.0220219    253
   7 │     7  0.303417     303
   8 │     8  0.409596     353
   9 │     9  0.165928     403
  10 │    10  0.752038     453
```

(I had initially misread the question and suggested logical indexing like `df[df.B .== 3, :]`)

Comment: You're essentially getting group 3. However, I wanted to get the third element of every group.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood

Comment: But maybe my edit isn't right either? You want 50 rows?